# Localhost connection closed not detected with select

Tags: c, winapi

I design a little web server in C winapi.

I use select to detect a 'connection closed' from the localhost (Firefox).

I launch a request with Firefox on my local server, and my software wait until I close the connection with Firefox (stop button).

If I close the connection from Firefox after about ten seconds, my software is able to detect the connection closed.

But, if I close the connection after one minute, my software doesn't detect anything...

ONLY, when I close Firefox, the connection closed is finally detected or ... finally closed by firefox ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detection of the closing of a socket can be very dependent on how/why the socket was closed along with other characteristics of the connection. I've found that one way to detect a closed connection in a reasonable amount of time is to attempt to write to the connection (as in establishing a periodic poll in both directions). That should result in an immediate error.

How this helps in your particular case, I'm not sure.

Comment: In my case: 1) Firefox send request. 2) My server hard work and must detect a firefox disconnection to cancel asap the hard work and cpu usage. 3) My server transmists partials results 4) Again, My server hard work and must detect a firefox disconnection to cancel asap, etc... and after the first transmission I am unable to detect the connection closed AS the firefox process is not completely terminated :( If i make a snd, i am able to detect a disconnection in all cases but my server have already done his hard work and this is not very optimized...